# How to use next_page in Django URL path

Tags: django, django-views

I have two URL class views from `django.contrib.auth`:

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
       template_name='accounts/login/login.html'), name='my_login'),


path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(
      template_name='accounts/logout/logout.html', next_page=XXXX), name='my_logout'),
```

What's the correct syntax to pass to `next_page` in the `LogoutView`? E.g.:

```
next_page='accounts/login/'
next_page='accounts/login/login.html'
next_page=my_login
next_page='my_login'
next_page=reverse_lazy('my_login')
```

Comment: `reverse_lazy('my_login')`. But here it does not make sense to both pass `template_name=...` and `next_page=...`, since the template is only rendered in case you have no `next_page`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't think that's correct. `LoginView` and `LogoutView` are not codependent.

Comment: a `LogoutView` will, given you provide a `next_page` redirect to that page, and never render something. It is only if you pass a `template_name`, and *no* `next_page`, that it will render a page instead.

Comment: I think you misunderstand templates in the sense that there is no relation between `urls` and templates. You can use the same template on multiple views (and hence urls), or use different templates in the same view. Outside the webserver templates do not exist, and in fact it is perfectly possible to create a Django website without any templates at all.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, If you pass `template_name` and `next_page`, it will still render `template_name`. `Next_page` is a redirect after the logout, not part of the rendering.

Comment: no, it overrides the `dispatch(..)` function (see https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.contrib.auth.views/LogoutView/ ), so that means that if a `next_page` is defined it redirects, regardless whether it is a GET/POST, etc. If there is no `next_page` it will, for GET/POST render a template. But by default this is some sort of "redirect" view: it logs out the user, and redirects to a page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `my_login` as value of `next_page` as per the [**`implementation`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/58df8aa40fe88f753ba79e091a52f236246260b3/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L129). Basically its using [**`resolve_url`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/shortcuts/).

```
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='my_login'), name='my_logout'),
```

But as @WillemVanOnsem said, you don't need to pass `template_name` as you will be redirecting to `my_login` url.